# How to retrieve data from local storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a hangman game and would like to store and retrieve the person's score and their username from the local storage and display it on the leader board `div`. How do I do this? I've seen most people use `localStorage.get` and `localStorage.set` but I'm not sure how to implement it here.

Thanks for the help.

This is my javascript code so far:

```
function storeUserDetails() {
  var userObject = {};

  userObject.name = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
  userObject.username = document.getElementById("usernameinput").value;
  userObject.password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;
  userObject.repeatpassword = document.getElementById("repeatpassinput").value;
  userObject.topscore = 0;

  localStorage[userObject.username] = JSON.stringify(userObject);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>Registration 
  Successful<br> Please <a href = '../PHP/login.php'><font color = 
  'orangered'>login</font></a></b>";
}

function checkLogin() {
  if (localStorage.loggedInUsername !== undefined) {
    var userObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUsername]);
  }
}

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("usernameinput").value;

  if (localStorage[username] === undefined) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>Username not found. Please sign up.</b>";
    return;
  } else {
    var userObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[username]); //Convert to object
    var password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;

    if (password === userObj.password) {
      localStorage.loggedInUsername = userObj.username; 
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
      window.location = "loggedin.php";
      /*sessionStorage.setItem('status', 'logged in');*/
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>Password incorrect. Please try again.</b>"
    }
  }
}

function updateScore() {
  rankingTable = document.getElementById("leaderboardcontainer");
  tableData = document.getElementById("content");
  //Username and score to be displayed here.
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage read docs and implement accordingly. The way you use `localStorage` right now is incorrect

Comment: *"I've seen most people use localStorage.get and localStorage.set"* - Where have you seen this?  What examples/tutorials have you been using?  Did you check the documentation?:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks. I shall check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use getItem, setItem and removeItem methods as shown in the documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks, I shall try it.